# In Trac, is it possible to add "text-decoration: line-through" as a custom __style__?

Tags: css, trac, line-through

I'm getting Trac 0.12.1 set up for the first time, and have written a few custom report queries.

However, I am having difficulty getting the custom `__style__` macro thingy (described  in the docs [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports#Customformattingcolumns)) to display a `text-decoration: line-through;` style.  It doesn't show up at all.

My query is roughly the following:

```
SELECT p.value AS __color__,
   (CASE status WHEN 'closed' THEN 'text-decoration: line-through' END)
      AS __style__,
   id AS ticket, priority, summary, version
  FROM ticket t
  LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
  ORDER BY version DESC, id DESC
```

This does not display closed tickets with line-through.  I can see it in the rendered page source, it is correctly formatted in the `style=""` attribute tag, as such:

```
  </tr>
  <tr class="color1-even" style="text-decoration: line-through;">
        <td class="ticket">
```

However, changing line 2 in the query above to read:

```
   (CASE status WHEN 'closed' THEN 'color: #666; background: #ccc' END)
```

It actually does show the row color and background as changing to a medium-gray color, so the style is definitely working.

Is anyone familiar enough with Trac to say why this may not be working, and provide a workaround?  Strike-through *really* helps to distinguish closed/invalid tickets.

It may be that `text-decoration:line-through` doesn't work across `tr` tags; if that is the case, is there a way to apply the Trac `__style__` only on one column (having it only on the `summary` would be fine.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tested out the following minimal HTML document:

```
<html><body>
<table border=1>
<tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
<tr style="text-decoration: line-through;"><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

The results were as expected (in both Firefox and IE).  The text in the last row had a line running through it.  I don't think having `text-decoration: line-through;` inside a `<tr>` element is your problem here.

Make sure that there isn't anything in any of your style sheets that might be overriding your inline CSS.  Try using `text-decoration: line-through !important` to override any other styles that may be present.  If this changes the behavior, then your problem is being caused by a conflicting definition in one of the style sheets.